# How can I overwrite the oldest record instead of creating a new one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

I am using Ruby on Rails 4 and in a `before_create` callback I would like to make it to overwrite an existing record instead of creating a new one in the database. That is, for example, given I have 10 records stored to a database table when I try to create a new record then the 11th record should overwrite the oldest record instead of creating a new one.

I tried the following code:

```
before_create do
  if more_than_ten?
    # Overwriting oldest record
    oldest_record = self.class.order(:created_at).first

    self.id = oldest_record.id
  else
    true
  end
end
```

But I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO ...)
```

How can I overwrite the oldest record instead of creating a new one?

Comment: Can't you just query in new and redirect to the oldest edit action if more than 10 exist?

Comment: @Baloo - I think you are referring to controller actions but in this case it is a model issue.

Comment: I am, and why is it a model issue?

If there are more than 10 then get the oldest and let them edit it.

Comment: @Baloo - It is a long story... basically, I would like to ensure conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the same ID as the original then you should be able to do the following

```
before_create do
 if more_than_ten?
   # Overwriting oldest record
   oldest_record = self.class.order(:created_at).first
   old_id = oldest_record.id
   oldest_record.destroy
   self.id = old_id
  else
    true
  end
end
```

and if you want to make sure it doesn't delete the old record when it fails you can ensure it gets wrapped in a transaction with `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction`

Comment: Will the `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` be enabled by default within the `before_create` callback? or, have I to state the `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` myself (as in your answer before editing)?

Comment: add `raiser "FAILED"` at the very end of the `before_create` callback to test if the records are actually destroyed when an error is raised. If yes => wrap with a transation, if not => you're good. @user502052

Comment: From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html): *"Both `save` and `destroy` come wrapped in a transaction that ensures that whatever you do in validations or callbacks will happen under its protected cover."*

Comment: What @Stefan said. I looked it up myself to ensure I was telling you right (hence the edit) and it will handle it's own transaction recovery. However I figured it was worth mentioning the ability to wrap things outside of creates and saves in transactions to ensure that things aren't destroyed when mistakes are made. Like if you wanted to call a specific function you could
`ActiveRecord::Base.transaction{
 func1
}`

Answer (score 2):

I see 2 options here:

- delete the oldest record and create a new one
- update the oldest record with the new one's attributes

We will go for the **first option**:

```
before_create do
  if more_than_ten?
    oldest_record = self.class.order(:created_at).last.destroy
  else
    true
  end
end
```

Short version:

```
before_create do
  self.class.order(:created_at).last.destroy if more_than_ten?
  true # if more_than_ten? return false, it will also return false for this before_create
end
```

**Why using the first option?** Because if we update the "oldest" record, the next time we will add a new record, it will update the same record (we rely on the `created_at` field).

We could use the `updated_at` field to rely on, but as @NickVeys said, you are in the `before_create` callback, which means if we update the oldest record with the attributes of the new record, we won't actually create a record. It is changing the default behavior of Rails (updates instead of create), and can lead to confusion (too much black magic can confuse even the best wizards!).

---

**Second option:** I think this cannot work since the before_create callback will not return true nor valid attributes for the object beeing created:

```
before_create do
  if more_than_ten?
    oldest_record = self.class.order(:created_at).last # get the record with the lowest created_at

    oldest_record.update_attributes(self.attributes.merge({ created_at: DateTime.current }))
    false # returns false to stop the creation process of the new record
  else
    true
  end
end
```

As you can see, we update the `created_at` field to `DateTime.now` to "simulate" that the object was created now. It solves the problem exposed above: next time we create a record, **it will not** use the same record (because the `.order(:created_at)` puts the newly updated object on top) but the other oldest record.

---

As @Stefan pointed it out, for the **option #1**, we should destroy every record after the 10th:

```
before_create do
  self.class.order(:created_at).offset(10).destroy_all
end
```

Comment: What if in the database I would like to keep using the `id` of the oldest record? What does it happen if the create transaction process fails after the `before_create` callback? The older record will be deleted in any case?

Comment: For the second option why do not update (in the `before_create` callback) even the `updated_at` attribute to the current time so that problems, as @NickVeys said, are avoided?

Comment: Why would you like to keep the id of the oldest record? If the before_create callback returns false (or add errors to the object beeing built), it will stop the transaction and do a rollback. I will update my answer with an update of the oldest record @user502052

Comment: There could be relations to other records, it's better to destroy the old record.

Comment: BTW, I think it would be more robust to destroy all but the last 10 entries in an `after_create` hook.

Comment: I admit I did not expose the full implementation of the class, but I would like to keep the `id` of the oldest record because I am afraid that `id` values' length will grow very quickly (the database column type is integer and should have a length "only" of 11 digits). In my case will the rollback avoid to destroy the oldest record?

Comment: You can use `reset_pk_sequence!` to reset the primary key sequence ;)

Comment: @MrYoshiji - The second option in your answer does not "replace" records and still creates a new one. What do you think about the **user3715522** answer? - P.S.: I think `reset_pk_sequence!` will not update all associated records.

Comment: Untested, but this would probably work: `after_create { self.class.order(:created_at).offset(10).destroy_all }`, you don't even need that `more_than_ten?` check

Comment: @Stefan - You are making too much assumptions. 10 was just an example in the question. The condition could be everything.

Comment: @user502052 I updated my second option with a `false` return to stop the creation process

Comment: So, if you return `false` then the creation process will stop at all making the model practically unusable.

Comment: This is exactly why I told you it is not an usual Rails behavior to update a record instead of creating one, especially in a `before_create` callback. You should re-think your logic about this "limit to ten records" functionnality and strongly consider `reset_pk_sequence!` ...

Comment: OK. Maybe I have to run the first option but you should correct your answer "by caring" / "since" (1) the `id` of the oldest record should be kept in the database for the new created record (2) the rollback should restore the destroying record to the database if something fails during the creation process.

Comment: (1): No, I will not post an answer that suggests to create a new record using the ID of the just-destroyed-record ; (2): This what @Micah explained in his answer. => Accept his answer since it fits your two last requirements. I will no steal the reputation that he deserves

Comment: (1) Why?! (2) OK, as you say. However it "seems" / "fills like" your answer should be accepted...

Comment: (1): This is not a conventional way to add a record. The DB manages the IDs, neither you or Rails. (2): Accept the answer that solved your problem, not the one that "feels like" it should be accepted...

Comment: @user502052 I don't understand why you are afraid of id column size, 11 digits is a lot: 99 999 999 999 is the last possible id. If you create a record every second, it would take ~27 777 777 hours to get to the last id! Which is also ~1 157 407 days ~= 3 170 years! The only way it could be limited is if you create like 1000 records per second (but I remember you that you limit it to be 10)!

Comment: that `11` in `INT(11)` is just the display width, the maximum value is 2,147,483,647. However, this can easily be changed to `BIGINT` for a maximum value of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a create, which maps to an insert statement.  Setting the ID to an existing record doesn't make it know what you want, it just sets the ID to an existing record, which for a primary key is not something your database cares for.

You'd need to delete that record before your insert for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but see my comments to the other questions.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this way:

```
before_create do
  if more_than_ten?
    self.id = self.class.oldest.id
    find(self.id).destroy
  end
  true
end

# You should use oldest scope
def self.oldest
  all.order(created_at: :desc).first
end
```

Or there is another way you can update the old record to the new one. The new record does not have id, so you can override the save method of ActiverRecord that do the job instead of using before_create.

```
def save
  more_than_ten? ? all.oldest.update(attributes) : super
end

def self.oldest
 all.order(created_at: :desc).first
end
```

Comment: What if in the database I would like to keep using the `id` of the oldest record? What does it happen if the create transaction process fails after the `before_create` callback? The older record will be deleted in any case?

Comment: The before_create is a part of the transaction creating current model. In the case of failure later it does not destroy anything. I fixed my code to use original id.